# Disable keypad or whole keyboard support on android activity?

Tags: android

I have a layout with lots of different imagebuttons on it.
Application is developed in full-touch, so there should be no response to keyboard or keypad on all activities except one, where user can input his name.
Is there a way to achieve that?

I've checked on debug, keypress and keypad press result in onKeyDown event.
I've set it to return 'false' for all keys.
But, for some reason, android keeps selecting my imagebuttons when keypad is pressed.
And pressing Enter key result in View.onClick event.

How to totally disable all keyboard input for activity?
I use Motorola Milestone for tests - a slider with a keyboard
Thanks

Comment: The user can use the keyboard instead of touching. You need to account for that. Don't limit the user's functional capabilities.

Comment: Ok, that's the general recommendation and I understand that. But what if, for example, you are required to have full-touch only support? Like, you was asked to remove all keyboard support?

Comment: Then it's a stupid requirement. You can have full touch support and have the keyboard support. Why is allowing the user access to the screen using a keyboard detrimental to your activity?

Comment: Well, sometimes we'r not in the position to discuss provided requirements. But, anyway, it will be good to have some kind of the solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` for the  tag in
the Manifest.xml file.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Oh sorry, this is only for the soft keyboard.

Comment: Yea, I've already checked that. Works only for soft keyboard, dpad keys keep working.